# Adding user control to a form at design-time throws the error "The remote computer refused the network connection"

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I've created one user control which has got a TextBox, a DataGridView, etc. When I try to drop the user control on the form I get this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the user control or its `DataGridView` trying to establish a connection with a database?

Comment: yes , but when i run the application its work and getting data without any problem

Comment: Well such things usually doesn't work at design-time. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've added a database connection through the designer. When you add the user control to a form it then tries to establish that connection, but doing so is usually not possible at design-time.

Instead, remove the connection you created through the designer and connect via code in the user control's [**`Load` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.load(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @HatemZn : If my answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark/tick on the left of my post. If it wasn't my answer that solved your problem then you should write your own answer explaining what the problem was and how to fix it, so that others with the same problem can see what worked for you.